# Html form get request not adding the form data

Tags: html, api, encoding

I'm making a desktop app that requires user to activate a key.

So the form here is making a get request to the api.

How do I make it so that when the user submits a form data (a key)
it is added as a parameter in the string?

UPDATE: Question answered.Thanks!

**But can anyone tell me how to make it so if the key is valid, the software loads, but if not then it throws an exception?**

```html
<form method="get"  formenctype="text/plain"  action="https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate?token=blahblahblah&ProductId=xxx2&Key=" >
 <input type="text"   maxlength="23" size="80" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you quite understand how GET works. Get sends data via the URI, any field(using the 'name' property) you add into your form is added to the query string.

```
<form method="get"  formenctype="text/plain"  action="https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate" >
 <input type="text" name="token"  maxlength="23" size="80" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" />
 <input type="text" name="ProductId"  maxlength="23" size="80" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" />   
 <input type="text" name="otherData"  maxlength="23" size="80" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" /> 
</form>
```

This will produce: https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate?token=VALUE&ProductId=VALUE&otherData=VALUE

Note I also removed the query string from the ACTION="" As the request will do that automatically for you.

EDIT: I also wouldn't recommend having your token in plain view. Either you make it a hidden field or you use javascript to execute the request with some masking. Hidden is usually fine providing the API has the necessary security to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hidden inputs` and naming them like the `GET` you need.
Check the name `token` with hidden value like example.
Remove all the `GET` from the **action-url**.

The final URL will be: 
`https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate?Key=yourKey&token=blahblahblah&ProductId=xxx2`

```
<form method="get"  formenctype="text/plain"  action="https://app.cryptolens.io/api/key/Activate" >
     <input type="text"   maxlength="23" size="80" name="Key" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" />
     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="blahblahblah" />
     <input type="hidden"   name="ProductId" value="xxx2" />    
</form>
```